# What kind of Arnoldi method is used in Mathematica?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, implementation-details

Can someone give me a bit more information about what mathematical method *Mathematica* is using, (preconditioner, filtering-restarting, deflation) in the Lanczos implementation when I input something like this:

```
{eig, eivec} = 
 Eigensystem[
  SparseArray[(Heff + ConjugateTranspose[Heff])/2], -1, 
  Method -> {"Arnoldi", "StartingVector" -> startvec, 
    "Tolerance" -> tolerance, "MaxIterations" -> iterations}]`
```

I want to always compute single eigenvalue with the smallest magnitude.

Comment: The implementation of the `Arnoldi` method uses the [ARPACK](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/) library.

Answer (score 6):

Quoting a comment by [@ilian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/ilian):

> The implementation of the `Arnoldi` method uses the [ARPACK](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/) library.